# Jemalloc output gives the memory address not the actual names

Tags: java, memory, memory-profiling, jemalloc

I am using Jemalloc to find out memory allocation of my application. I exactly follow the steps described here:https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwce/2.4.5/doc/html/GUID-231E1EFC-EA7C-4072-B0F4-0D92093D3161.html.

When I check the output using jeprof --show_bytes /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java jeprof.19678.0.f.heap

the output I can something like this :
6693878   0.1%  99.9%  6693878   0.1% 0x00007f1e8e033db7
  790901   0.0%  99.9%   790901   0.0% 0x00007f14deac7db7

I don't see the actual name of the method, but the memory address. How can I get the actual name of the method instead of the memory address.

Comment: did you find the answer to this? I'm struggling with this as well

Comment: try the raw option to see if it prints names: `jeprof --show_bytes --raw $JAVA_HOME/bin/java jeprof.xyz.heap`